# SQL Query to obtain the maximum value for each unique value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  Sum Name
a   10  Joe
a   8   Mary
b   21  Kate
b   110 Casey
b   67  Pierce
```

What would you recommend as the best way to 
obtain for each ID the name that corresponds to the largest sum (grouping by ID).
What I tried so far:

```
select ID, SUM(Sum) s, Name
from Table1
group by ID, Name
Order by SUM(Sum) DESC;
```

this will arrange the records into groups that have the highest sum first. Then I have to somehow flag those records and keep only those. Any tips or pointers? Thanks a lot

In the end I'd like to obtain:

```
a 10 Joe
b 110 Casey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `row_number()` function:

```
select id, [sum], name
from (select t.*]
             row_number() over (partition by id order by [sum] desc) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your question is more confusing than it needs to be because you have a column called `sum`.  You should avoid using SQL reserved words for identifiers.

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to a group of rows, starting with 1.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause.  In this case, all rows with the same `id` are in the same group.  The ordering of the numbers is determined by the `order by` clause, so the one with the largest value of `sum` gets the value of `1`.

If you might have duplicate maximum values and you want all of them, use the related function `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from
 (
   select *
    ,rn = row_number() over (partition by Id order by sum desc)
   from table
 )x
where x.rn=1
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17595)